# Как использовать application/json в связке с RX?

Tags: java, android

Интерфейс

```
public interface IApiRequest {

    @POST("/v1/register")
    Observable<ResponseBody> makeRegister(@Body ApiBody.MakeRegister register);
}
```

Запросы

```
public class ApiRequest {

    private static IApiRequest init(){
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://slife.auth.andviro.pw")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build().create(IApiRequest.class);
    }

    public static Observable<ResponseBody> makeRegister(String email, String password){
        return init().makeRegister(new ApiBody.MakeRegister(email,password));
    }
}
```

Вызовы

```
ApiRequest.makeRegister("chhdjd@mail.ru","sadasd22")
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {})
                .doFinally(() -> {})
                .subscribe(responseBody -> {
                    Log.e("Test", "main= " + responseBody.string());
                },Throwable::printStackTrace).dispose();
```

При запуске получаю ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class com.eranewgames.slife.network.ApiBody$MakeRegister (parameter #1)
for method IApiRequest.makeRegister
```

Проверив код в PostMan, там все работает без проблем. Что я не так сделал в коде?
Раньше я работал только с form/data типами. А тут application/json

Comment: проблему решил, был косяк на стороне сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit не знает как сериализовать твой объект `ApiBody.MakeRegister`. В билдере Retrofit-а укажи подходящий тебе ConverterFactory, например  `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())`

Comment: Да вы были правы, вот тоьлко запрос все равно не отправляется как json.  Я получаю всу ту же ошибку

`retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request`

Comment: Ну это уже совершенно другая ошибка, предположу что вам следует настроить правильную сериализацию в json. Gson сериализация по умолчанию может не удовлетворять требования сервера к запросу, не те имена полей или формат полей.

Comment: там нет сериализации, вы путаете что - то.

Comment: Ну конкретика бы не помешала. Я имел ввиду что Gson сериализовал ваш объект не так как этого ждёт сервер, о чём сервер и сообщил 400й ошибкой.